# Conditional link to node within views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have two content types, book and chapter.  Each chapter node contains a node reference of the book to which it belongs.  I have created a view which displays the title of each chapter for a given book.  Within the view, the title field has been configured to link to its node.

All works well.  I am now interested in updating the view to not display a link to a chapter's node when the chapter's body is empty.  Thus this view would display a list of chapter titles for a book and link only to those chapters that have a body.

Can this be accomplished using out of the box Views functionality?  If not, how would something like this be accomplished?

Thanks.

Comment: While this was asked in '09, we do have a sister site now that is specifically for drupal questions:  [drupal.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) module to implement your custom logic. It allows you to grab the data fetched by Views and manipulate it at will with PHP. Very handy.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer provided the information that I needed to have a conditional link for the title. What I did to accomplish this was to first download and enable views_customfield. Second, I placed Title and Body fields within the view, both excluded from display. Third, within a Customfield: PHP code field I placed the following code: <?php if (strlen(trim($data->node_revisions_body)) == 0) { return $data->node_title; } else { return l($data->node_title, drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $data->nid)); } ?>

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because my response to ceejayoz is poorly formatted.

What I did to accomplish this was to first download and enable views_customfield. Second, I placed Title and Body fields within the view, both excluded from display. Third, within a Customfield: PHP code field I placed the following code:

```
<?php
if (strlen(trim($data->node_revisions_body)) == 0) {
  return $data->node_title;
} else {
return l($data->node_title, drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $data->nid));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also this clever workaround which allows you to achieve this very easily:

> 1. Add 2 title fields one with link and one with no link, and make both
>      them exclude from display.
> 2. Add body field,
> 3. In No result behavior put title with no link replacement token to
>      it.
> 4. In Rewrite results behavior put title with link replacement token to
>      it.
> 5. Tick hide if empty.

[Source](https://www.drupal.org/node/489398#comment-7904581)